# Product (........ ) is over.PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, php-7, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

When added from a third-party product to the cart. I want to change the quantity of goods in the basket. Get alert Product (........ ) is over.

```
if(is_array($arCartPrice)){
        //if($arCartPrice['OPTIONS']['MINIMUM']>1){$QUANTITY=$arCartPrice['OPTIONS']['MINIMUM'];}else{$QUANTITY=1;}
        $QUANTITY=$arCartPrice['AVAILABLE_NUM'];
        $DefaultCategory = 12;
        $DefaultTaxGroup = 0;
        $Price = $arCartPrice['PRICE_CONVERTED'];
        $PriceVAT = round($Price);
        $Reference = $arCartPrice['ARTICLE'].' / '.$arCartPrice['BRAND'];

        //Presta init
        global $context;
        if(!$context){$context = Context::getContext();}
        $logged = $context->cookie->__get('logged');
        $id_cart = $context->cookie->__get('id_cart');
        $id_lang = $context->cookie->__get('id_lang');
        $id_guest = $context->cookie->__get('id_guest');
        $id_currency = $context->cookie->__get('id_currency');

        // Add cart if no cart found
        if (!$id_cart){
            $context->cart = new Cart();
            $context->cart->id_customer = $context->customer->id;
            $context->cart->id_currency = $id_currency;
            $context->cart->add();
            if($context->cart->id){
                $context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$context->cart->id;
            }
            $id_cart = (int)$context->cart->id;
        }

        $doAdd="Y";
        //if(!$logged>0){$doAdd="N"; $TCore->arErrorMessages[] = 'You must be <a href="/index.php?controller=my-account">logged in</a> to buy products';}
        //if(trim($Reference)=='' OR !$Price>0 OR !$QUANTITY>0){$doAdd="N"; $TCore->arErrorMessages[] = 'Add to cart data is missing!';}
        if(!$id_cart>0){$doAdd="N"; ErAdd("Your cookie <b>id_cart</b> is wrong!",1);}
        if(!$id_lang>0){$doAdd="N"; ErAdd("Your cookie <b>id_lang</b> is wrong!",1);}
        if($doAdd!="N"){
            //Check avail. tecdoc item in Presta
            $sql = 'SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`name` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`)
                    WHERE pl.`id_lang` = '.$id_lang.' AND
                    p.`price` = '.$Price.' AND
                    p.`reference` = "'.$Reference.'"
                    ';
            $arRes = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
            if(count($arRes)>0){
                $NewTID = $arRes[0]['id_product'];
            }else{
                    //Supplier data (for 1C integration)
                    $supplierName = $arCartPrice['SUPPLIER_STOCK'];
                    $supplierId = $suppliers = (Supplier::getIdByName($supplierName));
                    if (!$supplierId) {
                        $supplier = new Supplier();
                        $supplier->name = $supplierName;
                        $supplier->active = 1;
                        $supplier->add();
                        $supplierId = $supplier->id;
                    }

                    $obProduct = new Product(false,false,$id_lang);
                    $obProduct->id_category_default = $DefaultCategory;
                    $obProduct->unity = $arCartPrice['ADD_URL'];
                    $obProduct->name = $arCartPrice['ARTICLE'] .' / '.substr($arCartPrice['NAME'],0,400).' / '.$arCartPrice['BRAND'];
                    $obProduct->description = 'This product is created automatically by ';
                    $obProduct->description_short = $arCartPrice['SUPPLIER_STOCK'].' ['.$arCartPrice['DAY'].' days]';
                    $obProduct->price = $Price;
                    $obProduct->wholesale_price = $arCartPrice['PRICE'];
                    $obProduct->reference = $Reference;
                    $obProduct->link_rewrite = $arCartPrice['CPID'];
                    $obProduct->available_for_order = 1; //true
                    $obProduct->visibility = 'none';
                    $obProduct->is_virtual = 0;
                    //$obProduct->weight = round($arCartPrice['OPTIONS']['WEIGHT']/1000,2);
                    $obProduct->minimal_quantity = 1;
                    $obProduct->condition = 'used';
                    $obProduct->condition = 'refurbished';
                    $obProduct->available_now = $arCartPrice['AVAILABLE_NUM'];
                    $obProduct->quantity = $arCartPrice['AVAILABLE_NUM'];



                    //supplier
                    $obProduct->supplier_name = $supplierName;
                    $obProduct->id_supplier = $supplierId;

                    $obProduct->id_tax_rules_group = $DefaultTaxGroup;
                    //echo '<br><pre>';print_r($obProduct);echo '</pre>';die();
                    $obProduct->add();
                    if($obProduct->id>0){
                        $NewTID = $obProduct->id;
                        $obProduct->setWsCategories(Array(Array("id"=>$DefaultCategory)));
                        //Add image
                        if($arCartPrice['IMG_SRC']!='' AND $NewTID>0){
                            $shops = Shop::getShops(true, null, true);
                            $image = new Image();
                            $image->id_product = $NewTID;
                            $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($NewTID)+1;
                            $image->cover = true; // or false;
                            if(($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true && ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add()){
                                $image->associateTo($shops);
                                $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
                                if(Tools::copy($arCartPrice['IMG_SRC'], $tmpfile)){
                                    $path = $image->getPathForCreation();
                                    ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'.jpg');
                                }
                                unlink($tmpfile);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        ErAdd("Prestashop new Item ID is false",1);
                    }
                    unset($obProduct);
            }

            if($NewTID>0){
                //if($arCartPrice['AVAILABLE']>0){StockAvailable::setQuantity($NewTID, false, $arCartPrice['AVAILABLE']);}
                StockAvailable::setQuantity($NewTID, 0, (int) $arCartPrice['AVAILABLE']);
                $obCart = new Cart($id_cart);
                $obCart->id_lang = $id_lang;
                $obCart->id_currency = $id_currency;
                if($obCart->updateQty((int)$QUANTITY=1, (int)$NewTID)){
                    Header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); die();
                }else{
                    ErAdd(" Add to Cart is false. NewTID=".$NewTID,1);
                }
```

How to fix the code so you can update the quantity of goods in your cart.
And the number of 10 pieces. 1 piece is added to the cart. I want to add more to my cart. How to implement it? When I add 2 pieces. I receive a message Product (........ ) is over..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvmom.jpg)

Comment: You don't give us *nearly* enough information to allow us to respond meaningfully.  Remember that SO is not a code-writing nor a debugging service.  Give us a specific question, with enough information contained within the posting to allow us to understand it in context, and you're sure to get a quick reply.  But this question as posted is (IMHO ...) "unanswerable."  Good luck.  Please try again.

Comment: P.S.:  Be sure to check the contents of the underlying database where "sessions," "carts," and "cart contents" might be stored.  What do you see there?  *Do you* see that cart/basket?  *Do you* see that item in it?  *What is* the quantity now, according to the database?  These clues might help discover where the problem lies.  Also look at server request logs, on the server side, and browser debugging logs, on the client side.  *What are* the two sides actually saying to each other?  Might any of them be returning error-responses that you don't see?  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I add the item to the cart. When I want to increase the quantity of goods in the cart. Got a photo error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after you created the product, check in the Backoffice if the quantity is well stored (If the newly created product quantity is equal with $arCartPrice['AVAILABLE_NUM'] )
Maybe you can try with enabled "Allow ordering when out of stock" .